# What is :: before this keyword in React JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I see some syntax like below in some react-js libraries. What is that mean and how can help me in my codes?

```
const inputAttributes = {
  id: 'events-playground',
  placeholder: 'Where are you now?',
  onChange: ::this.onInputChanged,
  onBlur: ::this.onInputBlurred
};
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It is new ES7 syntax for [.bind](http://blog.jeremyfairbank.com/javascript/javascript-es7-function-bind-syntax/),

equivalent in ES5

```
const inputAttributes = {
  id: 'events-playground',
  placeholder: 'Where are you now?',
  onChange: this.onInputChanged.bind(this),
  onBlur: this.onInputBlurred.bind(this)
};
```

Comment: Thanks. Can I use it in my react code, or there's a limitation in use?

Comment: Could you link to a documentation for this